# Broken XMonad (Dependencies) after Pacman Update (How to compile it with Stack?)

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, xmonad, xmonad-contrib

> This question is the distilled solution of what others have helped me solved. The discussion can be found on [this issue](https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad/issues/301) and [this r/xmonad post](https://www.reddit.com/r/xmonad/comments/nkayyu/help_with_broken_xmonad_after_pacman_update/).

I'm using Artix mainly with Pacman as a package manager. Today, after about a week, I've upgraded many packages and it ended up breaking XMonad.

This is the message I get from `xmonad --recompile -v`:

```
XMonad is recompiling and replacing itself another XMonad process because the current process is called "xmonad" but the compiled configuration should be called "xmonad-x86_64-linux"
XMonad will use ghc to recompile, because "/home/philippe/.xmonad/build" does not exist.
XMonad skipping recompile because it is not forced (e.g. via --recompile), and neither xmonad.hs nor any *.hs / *.lhs / *.hsc files in lib/ have been changed.
/home/philippe/.xmonad/xmonad-x86_64-linux: error while loading shared libraries: libHSxmonad-contrib-0.16-KKfUmtIonstICqbgIKQKYh-ghc8.10.4.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've tried a ton of solutions people mentioned on the internet — so far I've spent more than 3 hours trying to debug this —, among them, notably:

- `cabal install --lib xmonad-contrib`, which had solved some issues I've had with XMonad in the past.
- Removing and reinstalling Stack, GHC, Cabal, and XMonad itself.
- Installing XMonad through Stack.

  - This ended up giving me the same error message, the difference is that I had to execute `~/.local/bin/xmonad --recompile -v` instead.

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this? I've had problems with upgrades of XMonad before, but never anything close to this — I love Haskell as a language, but its package management is one of the most disgusting, overcomplicated pieces of software I've ever experienced in my 10+ years of programming life.

If I end up cleaning up my system and managing everything through Stack, how do I compile XMonad through it? Using only Stack and then `xmonad --recompile` is giving me this error:

```
XMonad will use ghc to recompile, because "/home/philippe/.xmonad/build" does not exist.
xmonad: ghc: runProcess: runInteractiveProcess: exec: inappropriate type (Not a directory)
```

(I do have an `~/.xmonad/build/` folder by the way...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally made it work. The guys from the XMonad repo really helped, you can check out their help in [this issue](https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad/issues/301).

Roughly, what I did was:

1. Delete everything Haskell-related from my system.

   - Do this one carefully, use a lot of `find`s with the words *haskell*, *stack*, *ghc*, *cabal*, etc. Don't forget to use `pacman -Rns` and `pacman -Q` to uninstall everything that come from there first.
   - As some other users mentioned, you should absolutely *not* manage Haskell packages with both Pacman/AUR and Stack/Cabal. Choose one system and stick to it. Stack is probably the recommended one.
2. Install Stack directly with the [script on its documentation](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/#how-to-install).
3. Install GHC, XMonad, and XMonad-Contrib through Stack.
4. Create a [build script](https://github.com/slotThe/xmonad/blob/new-tutorial/INSTALL.md#tell-xmonad-how-to-recompile-itself) for compiling XMonad with Stack:

   ```sh
   #!/bin/sh

   exec stack ghc --  \
     --make xmonad.hs \
     -i               \
     -ilib            \
     -fforce-recomp   \
     -main-is main    \
     -v0              \
     -o "$1"jk
   ```
5. Add `exec $HOME/.xmonad/xmonad-x86_64-linux` to `.xinitrc` so it runs what was compiled with Stack previously.